# Does the Google AJAX API Loader have any advantage over direct link to Google hosted files via script tag?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, loader

I've recently moved a site over to use the Google AJAX Libraries instead of hosting the library js files myself. At the moment I'm using the Google recommended approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=MYAPIKEY"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">google.load('jquery', '1.3.2');</script>
```

But it seems a little silly to me to include an extra JavaScript file, just so I can call another script file.

My question is, is there actually any advantage to calling these files via `google.load()` as opposed to simply including them via script tag like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My main reasons for using the Google hosted libraries are the speed of their CDN/edge caching systems; am I still getting those benefits if I link directly to the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the main advantage for using the loader api is that you will prevent blocking by the browser when its doing the initial downloads. Browsers can only download between 2 & 10 things at a time so if there is blocking it will give bad user experience

[Steve Souders](http://stevesouders.com/) and the [Yahoo! Exceptional Performance team](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/) have done a lot of research into this to get faster websites. Nick Zakas (JavaScript guru) blogged about using Steve's ideas [here](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/23/loading-javascript-without-blocking/)

Comment: But that HTTP connection limit only applies per domain, so if I link to the file on Google's servers it's not relevant anyway - content from my server will still download concurrently. Plus, I'm still synchronously loading the JS for the API itself, which is only marginally smaller than the jQuery JS.

Comment: If its just for jQuery then I would just use the script tag because it will still the same CDNs. If you wanted to use jQuery and jQuery UI and <insert other thing you want download here> then the API would be more benefitial

Comment: Ah, I see, so you're saying that if I was loading *multiple* libraries from Google then the API loader would allow me to do that in a non-blocking way, but it's not really worth it just for one library. Thanks!